# How to determine storage quota used by each google service?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, gmail-api

My questions all revolve around trying to work out how much storage each google service is contributing toward a user's storage quota.

[Version 2 of the Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get) itemizes the user's storage quota into it's service components. eg: drive, gmail, photos,...

```
{
    "quotaBytesTotal": "16106127360",
    "quotaBytesUsed": "8815339193",
    "quotaBytesUsedAggregate": "11518850915",
    "quotaBytesUsedInTrash": "3690146836",
    "quotaType": "LIMITED",
    "quotaBytesByService": [
        {
            "serviceName": "DRIVE",
            "bytesUsed": "8815302329"
        },
        {
            "serviceName": "GMAIL",
            "bytesUsed": "2696242936"
        },
        {
            "serviceName": "PHOTOS",
            "bytesUsed": "7268786"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Version 3 of Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/about/get) returns only Drive's contribution toward the user's total storage quota...

```
{
    "storageQuota": {
        "limit": "16106127360",
        "usage": "11518850915",
        "usageInDrive": "8815339193",
        "usageInDriveTrash": "3690146836"
    }
}
```

1. Have I missed someplace in the V3 API of Drive which provides the previous functionality detailing how much each service is contributing?
2. (If not) Is the intent of this change documented or blogged about anywhere?  Is there a direction/methodology they're working toward which indicates what we might see appearing in other API's sometime?
3. How long until V2 is decommissioned and we're forced to migrate to V3?
4. To get the same data will I have to authenticate each and every service to get the quota contribution?
5. Which API reveals the `GMAIL` storage usage now?
6. Which API reveals the `PHOTOS` storage usage now?
7. How might I establish which services are using enough quota to warrant a request for access to-to get their Available vs Used numbers?

Thanks

Comment: fwiw: I found [the blog post announcing the drive/gmail/photos quota unification](http://googledrive.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/bringing-it-all-together-15-gb-now.html) and [supplemental API post](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/what-does-storage-quota-unification.html).

Comment: forget about the [admin reports api](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/userUsageReport/get)... even if it had what we sought it would only be for a specific day and certainly days old.